# How to extract exact set of div tag in C# using Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, regex

```
<div id="bulletinContents">
    <div class="headingArea">
        <div id="heading">
            Critical Notice Description:&nbsp<br>
            Notice Effective Date:&nbsp<br>
        </div>

        <div id="headingData">Critical notice<br>
            10/16/2013<br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="bulletin">
        <br>
        <div id="Div1">Notice Text:</div>
        <br>
        To notify
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

there are also other `<div>` tags on the page, but I want to extract this particular section.

Can anyone please suggest me a proper regular expression for this.

I have used this regex:

```
<div[^>]*>(?<Value>[^<]*(?:(?!</div)<[^<]*)*)[</div>]*
```

but it does not give me proper content. It returns only the `<div>` with id **heading** and **Div1**.

I need to complete this task only by using regular expression and nothing else. Please suggest me proper Regex to do it.

Comment: the regex used by me is @"<div[^>]*>(?<Value>[^<]*(?:(?!</div)<[^<]*)*)[</div>]*

Comment: Don't use `REGEX` to get data from `HTML`!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I know its tedious but i have to use regex its compulsion. So please help me out

Comment: I really hate `Regex` the only think I can suggest you it's a HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: Do you mean the div with id='bulletinContents '?

Comment: Here we go [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)...